# PHP Оставить в тексте только слова через пробел

Tags: php

Допустим есть текст:

```
Привет всем!

Меня зовут «Вася»
Я мечтаю стать космонавтом)
```

Мне нужно получить:

```
Привет всем Меня зовут Вася Я мечтаю стать космонавтом
```

В лоб получилось так:

```
$str0 = '<Здесь исходный текст>';
$flag = false;
$str = '';
for ($i=0; $i<mb_strLen($str0, 'utf-8'); $i++){
    $c = mb_substr($str0, $i, 1, 'utf-8');
    if (preg_match("/^[a-zа-яA-ZА-ЯёЁ]/u", $c)){
        $flag = true;
        $str .= $c;
    } else if ($flag) {
        $flag = false;
        $str .= ' ';
    }
}
echo $str;
```

На больших текстах, конечно же, очень тормозит.
Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^ a-zа-яё\d]/ui', '',$str );` и всё, зачем эти условия и т.п..? Флаг `i` позволяет оставить в регулярке только нижний регистр

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а зачем же на каждый символ регулярку запускать? они и так медленно работают. Так должно быть повеселее

```
$str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $str);
echo preg_replace('/[^a-zа-яA-ZА-ЯёЁ ]/u', '', $str);
```